# MUI components return Uncaught TypeError error message

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Thanks for the help in advance. I am using MUI on a react project that I am working. In it some components doesn't works and I am getting Uncaught TypeError error message. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue. My code is given below

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, Container, Box, Button, Typography } from "@mui/material";
const BannerSlider = () => {
    return (
        <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Container maxWidth="xl" className="custom-slider" sx={{ padding: "0!important" }}>
                    <Box className="custom-slider-itemWrap">
                        <Box className="custom-slider-item">
                            <Grid container>
                                <Grid item lg={7}>
                                    <div className="custom-slider-newLabel">
                                        <Typography variant="body1">
                                            <span>New</span>Stay connected to the upcoming & Recent jobs
                                        </Typography>
                                    </div>
                                    <Typography variant="h1">Your Solution Legal Consultacy</Typography>
                                    <Typography variant="body1">We are here to help you take care of your legality with the best service especially for you.</Typography>
                                    <Button variant="contained">GET STARTED</Button>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item lg={5}></Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                </Container>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
};

export default BannerSlider;
```

My error

[image]

Comment: I've tried the code in stackblitz and it doesn't give any error

Comment: thanks for the help I am still getting this error but when I comment this component the project runs other I am getting a white screen only

Comment: Maybe trying `component=` instead of `variant=`

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to fix this in the end?

I just had a very similar problem and found I'd written the theme provider with an extra set of curly brackets like this:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={{theme}}/>
  <App />
<ThemeProvider/>
```

Instead of:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}/>
  <App />
<ThemeProvider/>
```